# Using Loop to Create Choices in Google Forms with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have the following code

```
function updateFormTwo() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form 1 Responses");
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
var lastRow = range.getLastRow();
var values = range.getValues();
var i = 0;
var dropdown = [[0,0,0]];
var dd = [];
var ddarray = [];

var form = FormApp.openById("1w-IrMmda....0etp5gW-sfAk");
var item = form.getItems();
Logger.log(item);
var list = item[0].asListItem();
var j = 0;

for (i=0; i < lastRow-1; i++){

dropdown[i][0] = values[i+1][1];
dropdown[i][1] = values[i+1][9];
dropdown[i][2] = values[i+1][10];
dd[i] = dropdown[i][0] + " - " + dropdown[i][1] + " - " + dropdown[i][2];
ddarray.push( list.createChoice( dd[i] ) );

}

list.setChoices([ddarray]);
}
```

I am trying to get 3 cells per row from a Google Spreadsheet, concatenate them, and then have them all appear on a dropdown menu on another Google Form. I am coming up short.

The error I get is

> Cannot convert Array to Choice[].

What do I have wrong? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried "hard coding" the array values in `list.setChoices([ddarray]);` to see if it works?  That way, you can know if it's the data, or it's something else in the code.

Comment: I haven't tried that yet. I will probably try that in the next little bit unless somebody else spots why this isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
function updateFormTwo() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form 1 Responses");
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
var lastRow = range.getLastRow();
var values = range.getValues();
var i = 0;
var j = 0;

//create 2D Array
var dropdown = new Array();

for (i = 0; i < lastRow - 1; i++){

dropdown[i] = new Array();

for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){

 dropdown[i][j] = 0; 

}

}

var dd = [];

var form = FormApp.openById("1w-IrMmdaY...gW-sfAk");
var item = form.getItems();

var list = item[0].asListItem();

for (i = 0; i < lastRow - 1; i++){

dropdown[i][0] = values[i+1][1];
dropdown[i][1] = values[i+1][9];
dropdown[i][2] = values[i+1][10];
dd[i] = dropdown[i][0] + " - " + dropdown[i][1] + " - " + dropdown[i][2];

}

Logger.log(dd);

list.setChoiceValues(dd);
}
```

First, I got rid of the `ddarray` variable and used `list.setChoiceValues(dd);` instead of `ddarray.push( list.createChoice( dd[i] ) )` in the second for loop and then `list.setChoices([ddarray]);`.

After that, I created the for loop to give the array the exact dimensions. I noticed that my first fix worked when I had the correct array dimensions so it was given that I needed a loop to create the exact dimensions as the number of rows increased.

Comment: To make this answer useful, it needs some explanation. What was the problem? How did you figure it out (what would someone with a similar problem look for)? And, most importantly: How did you fix it?

Comment: @Mogsdad Great questions. I will update the answer with what I found to be the problem.